# Can we create a list that contains three lists with different amount of values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have been researching for a way to create a List that contains Multiple lists of int and string such as:
Parent List will contain children lists and each child list contains two items (ID and Name) that doesn't have to be equal in number of items(this is why I can't use Tuples
**Example:**
parent List      child List One    ID = many
Name = 1
to add values we do:

```
parentList.childListOne.ID.ADD(something) 
parentList.childListOne.Name.ADD(something)
```

If there are a better way to achieve this as well that is appreciated.
I understand the question is not greatly worded but this is to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Are you stuck on something specific? Search for "list of lists" or "jagged arrays" to get some ideas

Comment: `parentList` can't be a list with a property `childListOne`: `List<T>` does not have such a property. Why do you call it `parentList`? What is its type? Also, are you trying to say there can be more than one ID and Name and the numbers don't have to match?

Answer (score 0):

> this is why I can't use Tuples

Sure you can:

```
(string Name, int Id) tuple = ("John", 1);

var listOfTuples = new List<(string, int)>();

listOfTuples.Add(tuple);

var listOf_listOfTuples = new List<List<(string, int)>>();

listOf_listOfTuples.Add(listOfTuples);

//add another person to the first list 
listOf_listOfTuples[0].Add(("Mary", 2));

//add another list of tuples
listOf_listOfTuples.Add(new List<(string, int)>());

//add 3 people to the second list of tuples
listOf_listOfTuples[1].Add(("Joe", 3));
listOf_listOfTuples[1].Add(("Jake", 4));
listOf_listOfTuples[1].Add(("Jack", 3));
```

But you can't access them like you've done, because it isn't legal c# when working with collections; you have to index List by number, not name. If you want named property access you'll have to derive from List and add the properties

Comment: Here we can't add ("joe", no value)// this is my goal

Comment: Er.. No, but that's either because it's an `int` which cannot "not have a value" but is easy to change for an `int?` which can "not have a value", or you need to swap it for something else if you're hoping to omit it entirely, such as `List<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>` but by the time youre getting to that level of nesting datacontainers, your design is going probably wrong and you need something else

Comment: While hard to understand, I believe the original question is meant to imply that the number of Names and IDs do not match.